# Aggregating labels in GradientBoostingRegression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I am trying to understand Scikit-Learn's  Gradient Boosting Regression algorithm.  I followed their source code and have a good understanding of their iterative construction of trees based on a chosen loss function.  What I couldn't figure out an answer to is how do they take the average of the labels from all underlying estimators when I invoke  `predict()` .

I followed that function call down to [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/_gradient_boosting.pyx#L95).  Here,  `scale`  holds the  `learning_rate` , which if not provided, will default to 0.1.  So, if I were to use 500 trees, I don't understand why would they be multiplying each of 500 different labels, for a given sample, by 0.1.

If someone could direct me to a published paper that explains this in depth, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#regularization)